# What kind of displays and processors are used in consumer electronic products (like a coffee machine)?

Tags: display, manufacturing, production, appliances, graphics

I am presently working on the development of a smart kitchen appliance, which will eventually be sold in the market. As part of this project, I need to incorporate a touch display for the operation of the device. For the initial prototype, I utilized a 5-inch Waveshare display with a Raspberry Pi. However, since I am now focused on turning this into a market-ready product, I am seeking information on the types of displays suitable for commercial purposes.

My product is similar to a high-end coffee machine equipped with a touchscreen interface. I would like to know which display options are most appropriate for a commercial-grade product of this kind. Additionally, I am curious about how are these displays operated?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the answer would be a list and/or not useful over time.

Comment: @Santosh At present this looks somewhat like a "shopping question" regardless of how you intended it. The 3 close voters probably saw it that way. The "off topic" reason given MAY be becaus of te inflexibility of the system. || If you can dit this to make it more obvious that you want design suggestions and what form these ma take it can probably be reopened. If you do this thn please click the "Reopen" button AND ALSO flag it for admin attention.

Comment: I've reopened and reclosed the question and changed the reason to "needs details or clarity" -  which is prbably a better fit.

Comment: Santosh - For an excellent  forum that supports discussion look at http://www.piclist.com (don't be put off by the presentation or the PIC in the name). Then visit http://mailman.mit.edu/mailman/listinfo/piclist, join the mailing list & say hello. Provide as much detail of your requirements as possible. 
 Just like here, there are people there who know almost everything (collectively). The site supports a conversational approach. Some SE members are also PICList members (myself included). It's a very useful complement to this site for questions of this sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, for that size of display, your folks would source an LCD module with touch interface that has an flat cable to run to your custom PCB, either plugged in or bonded in some other way.

The selected processor would typically be one that has an on-chip graphic LCD controller and enough RAM for a frame buffer. You might also choose to have an external frame buffer RAM chip and/or external flash storage for graphics. These days such processors are almost always 32-bit.

Selecting a suitable display and processor involves a lot of non-technical considerations and business decisions, and maybe even factory visits for a high volume product. If you pick the wrong display and its discontinued in 6 months, a lot of cost and shipment delays could result. Similarly with processors, if the part is technically available to order but new shipments are not expected until Q4 2024 that could put a damper on the product roll-out.